# RSA key generation error in RSA_generate_key_ex function call

Tags: openssl, rsa, bios, uefi, edk2

I'm trying to generate RSA keys using openssl. I've got error on `RSA_generate_key_ex` and have no idea why the error occures.

I combine `ERR_get_error()` and `ERR_error_string()` and I've got next message: `error:2506906C:lib(37):func(105):reason(108)`. Also I found out that 108 error code means *RSA_R_DATA_GREATER_THAN_MOD_LEN*

I'm trying to generate RSA keys using C code below. For sake of brevity I reduce free calls and error output

```
RSA* generateRSA()
{
  BIGNUM *bne = BN_new();
  if (bne == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (BN_set_word(bne, RSA_F4) != 1)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  RSA *r = RSA_new();
  if (r == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  // THERE I'VE GOT ERROR
  if (RSA_generate_key_ex(r, 2048, bne, NULL)!= 1)
  {
    // ERR_get_error() returns 2506906C
    // ERR_error_string() gives me RSA_R_DATA_GREATER_THAN_MOD_LEN
    return NULL;
  }

  return r;
}
```

The question is what does the error mean and how can I fix it?

**Edit**: I use OpenSSL 1.1.0e 16 Feb 2017. I use it as part of [EDK II Project](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2)

Comment: What version of OpenSSL are you using. I just tried your to compile and run your code against both 1.1.1 and 1.0.2, and it worked just fine in both. The key was generated without any errors

Comment: @MattCaswell, I use OpenSSL 1.1.0e 16 Feb 2017. But I use it as part of EDK II Project (https://github.com/tianocore/edk2). So I think I need to edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that random generator need to be seeded (openssl versions 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 random generators must be explicitly seeded).

I check `RAND_status()`. It returned 0. So the solution is just add `RAND_seed()` before key generation:

```
const void* getSeedBuffer(int num);

RSA* generateRSA()
{
  RAND_seed(getSeedBuffer(1000), 1000); // don't forget to free memory
  BIGNUM *bne = BN_new();
  if (bne == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (BN_set_word(bne, RSA_F4) != 1)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  RSA *r = RSA_new();
  if (r == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (RSA_generate_key_ex(r, 2048, bne, NULL)!= 1)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  return r;
}
```

Comment: "I figured out that random generator need to be seeded (openssl versions 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 random generators must be explicitly seeded)." - most of the time this isn't the case. It will automatically seed. However in certain environments this might not happen. Looking at the EDK II Project - I guess that can be one of those cases.